# Exporting Query as Shared Workbook

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I've got code that'll iterate through my queries of choice and export them as standard .xls files.

My question is, how can I export these as Shared Workbooks?

A team at work uses about 20 workbooks, and they manually have to set them as shared so they all can access them at teh same time.

Currently, to output, I run the command:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acQuery, Query, acFormatXLS, output_folder & DirectoryFriendlyQuery & ".xls", False, "", 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be among your options.  I don't see how to do it.  Hopefully you can address this at the system level (in other words, get them all on Access).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use office automation. Set a reference to your Microsoft Excel object library from the VBA IDE (alt+F11) >> Tool >> References.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, wb As Excel.Workbook`

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myfile)
wb.SaveAs accessmode:=xlShared, FileName:=myfile
wb.Close savechanges:=false
Set sb = Nothing
xlApp.Quit`
```

To make this a bit speedier by not having to save the file twice (one in access and again in excel) you can create the worksheet in memory.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, wb As Excel.Workbook, sh as excel.worksheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=myfile)
set sh = wb.worksheets.add()
sh.cells(1,1).copyfromrecordset Data:=currentdb.openrecordset(name:="myquery")
wb.SaveAs accessmode:=xlShared, FileName:=myfile
wb.Close savechanges:=false
Set sb = Nothing
xlApp.Quit`
```